# I have to circumvent ngModelController.$parsers to store a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I just opened a [bug report about how ngModelController.$parsers does not work on Chrome, Safari, or FireFox](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14273).  However, the application that I am working on that prompted that bug report to be entered is still an ongoing project, and one that I need to find a workaround for.

The following codes *does not* work due to the bug.  This code uses [jQuery Masked Input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) as well as Angular 1.5:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    // Build mask.
    var mask = '99999?-9999';
    $(element).mask(mask);

    // Store all zip codes without non-digit characters
    // E.G.: 12345-6789 -> 123456789
    //       12345 -> 12345
    ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
        var nonDigitCharacters = /[^0-9]/g;
        var digitsOnly = viewValue.replace(nonDigitCharacters, '');

        return digitsOnly;
    });

    ctrl.$formatters.push(function (value) {
        return $filter('zip')(value, false);
    });
}
```

However, I really don't know any other ways to apply the current `$viewValue` to the model, without using a `ngModelController.$parser` function.  I'm considering doing something like this:

```
$(element).on('keyup', function () {
    var nonDigitCharacters = /[^0-9]/g,
        digitsOnly = ctrl.$viewValue.replace(nonDigitCharacters, '');

    // Something with digitsOnly?
});
```

...As a temporary workaround, but I do not know what exactly to do.

**Question:** What are some options for applying a value directly to the model from a directive?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a work around.  Pretty much...you have to brute force this sort of thing.

What `ngModelController.$parsers` does behind the scenes pretty much is the following list:

1. Get the current `$viewvalue`, by reading the element's value.
2. Pass the `$viewValue` into the current `$parser` function
3. Take the result of that `$parser` function; pass it into the next one.
4. Repeat until done.
5. Apply the result of all `$parser` functions to the model directly.

...Pretty much, I had to hand-replicate that as below:

```
$(element).on('keyup', function() {
    ctrl.$setViewValue($(element).val());
    var nonDigitCharacters = /[^0-9]/g,
        digitsOnly = ctrl.$viewValue.replace(nonDigitCharacters, '');

    var model = $parse(attrs.ngModel),
        modelSetter = model.assign;

    scope.$apply(function () {
        modelSetter(scope, digitsOnly);
    });
});
```

Doing that will allow you to circumvent `ngModelController.$parsers` directly.  That being said, I'm not sure if there are any subtleties that I am missing that one would need to be aware of.  Hopefully this can tide me over until the bug is looked into and either a better workaround found, or a fix for the bug administered by the Angular team.